# React router v6 render changed to children not working

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom, react-typescript

I have a code react router domain v5

```
export const AuthenticateRoute: FC<RouteProps> = ({
  component: Component,
  ...rest
}) => {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) =>
        Component && validtoken() ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={`/login?msg=expired`}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};
```

Now I am trying to convert this in v6 as I founder render as been changed from docs

> props, just use regular element

export const AuthenticateRoute: FC = ({
component: Component,
...rest
}) => {
return (
<Route
{...rest}
children={(props) =>
Component && validtoken() ? (
<Component {...props} />
) : (
<Redirect
to={`/login?msg=expired`}
/>
)
}
/>
);
};

But its not working, its throwing an error, since I have tried many way so each time getting different error, mostly I was getting

> Type '() => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'

Any help

Thanks